# Problems with react & material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

It shows hook err, but the thing is I do not have any hooks.Only Material UI causes this problem. If i delete these strings after return, it works

Project code:

````
    import React from 'react'
    import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid } from '@mui/material'
    import memories from './images/memories.png'
    
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <Container maxwidth='lg'>
          <AppBar position='static' color='inherit'>
            <Typography variant='h2' align='center'>
              Memories
            </Typography>
            <img src={memories} alt='memories' height='60' />
          </AppBar>
        </Container>
      )
    }

export default App```

error:

    Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
````

Comment: I tried to edit your post and then you undo it, weird, your code box is ugly and contains ``` at the end of your component `App`. another thing. when a user tries to fix your dictation do not undo it. Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you used some hooks inside index,js file.
i have copied your code into my editor and removed img tag and

```
import memories from './images/memories.png'
```

and everything worked.